# Defining Foreign Key in Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, foreign-key-relationship, entity-framework-core

In the following Model example (taken from this [official ASP.NET site](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/new-db.html#create-your-model)) I understand they are defining a Foreign Key relationship between `Blogs` (parent) and `Posts` (Child) tables. But in the Blog class below what is the use of `public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }` property? If I remove this property and generate SQL Server database out of this Model, I can still see database was successfully created with `BlogId` in `Posts` table as Foreign Key to `Blog` table

```
namespace EFGetStarted.AspNetCore.NewDb.Models
{
    public class BloggingContext : DbContext
    {
        public BloggingContext(DbContextOptions<BloggingContext> options)
            : base(options)
        { }

        public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }

    public class Blog
    {
        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }

        public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }

    public class Post
    {
        public int PostId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }

        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public Blog Blog { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: `List<Post> Posts` is a [navigation property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713564(v=vs.113).aspxf) which makes it convenient to access Posts from a Blog.

Comment: @Jasen your link is broken, it should be https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713564(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Seems I copied in an additional letter at the end of that URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nam,

The `Posts` property in the `Blog` class could be useful if you have the need to access the posts directly from an instance of a `Blog` object.

Loading the posts could be done via lazy loading or Entity Framework Eager loading using the Include method:

```
    var blogs1 = context.Blogs 
                      .Include(b => b.Posts) 
                      .ToList();
```

If you remove it will not prevent the database to be properly created.

Comment: Actually EfCore doesn't support lazy loading yet, you have to use Include. And just to clarify the FK is created based on BlogId, the Posts property is merely a navigation property.

Comment: @VivienChevallier So your query is saying give me all `posts of which blog`? Or, your query is saying give me each blog along with all the posts associated with each blog. In other words, it's another way of writing a LINQ JOIN between Blogs and Posts tables. I'm trying to understand your response before marking it as an `Answer`.

Comment: @nam My query is saying: give me each blog along with all the posts associated with each blog.

Comment: @VivienChevallier And this query would have not worked without the property `public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }` used in the Blog Class?

Comment: Exactly, you would not have been able to write it.